# How to generate a mutable identity matrix in Scala?

Tags: scala, matrix

I must create an identity matrix in Scala and without using `zipWithIndex` (I successfully tried to use `zipWithIndex`, but it caused some problems because of the resulting `IndexedSeq`). The type of it must be : `mutable.Seq[mutable.Seq[Double]]`.

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.Seq
def identity(dim: Int): Seq[Seq[Double]] = {
  Seq.tabulate(dim)(r => Seq.tabulate(dim)(c => if(r == c) 1.0 else 0.0))
}
```